# Convert a random number to a datetime in Pandas

Tags: datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataset:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,3],[2,3,1],[1,3,4]],columns=['C1','C2','C3'])
```

...and I want to do two things:

1. Create a random number column
2. Convert that random number to a random date variable

The range of the dates doesn't matter as long as they are random and there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,3],[2,3,1],[1,3,4]],columns=['C1','C2','C3'])
data['X'] = np.random.choice(len(data), len(data), replace=False)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['X'], unit='D')
```

yields (something like)

```
   C1  C2  C3  X       date
0   1   3   3  2 1970-01-03
1   2   3   1  0 1970-01-01
2   1   3   4  1 1970-01-02
```

`np.random.choice` with `replace=False` will guarantee that there are no duplicates.